# How to install apt package in debian?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

I am having Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.4 (squeeze). By mistake all the apt files are removed from my OS. I am trying to install package "apt_0.9.7.1_amd64.deb". But while installing the package i am getting the following errors :

```
Unpacking replacement apt ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.9.7.1); however:
  Package libapt-pkg4.12 is not installed.
 apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Version of libstdc++6 on system is 4.4.5-8.
 apt depends on debian-archive-keyring; however:
  Package debian-archive-keyring is not installed.
dpkg: error processing apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

Can anyone know how to install the apt package? or are there any other ways to install the package.

While using any command like sudo apt-get update etc. I am getting error

```
apt : Depends: debian-archive-keyring but it is not going to be installed
```

For installing debian-archive-keyring I need apt and for apt I need debian-archive-keyring.
Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Hi there. This site is for programming questions. You may want to try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 1):

Since `apt` is no longer present on your system you'll have to fix this manually.

For me this worked on Ubuntu 13.10:

Downloaded `apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb`:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apt

Try to install it using `dpkg`:

> sudo dpkg -i  apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb

You might get error like:

```
Unpacking apt (from apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.9.16); however:
  Version of libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 on system is 0.9.9.1~ubuntu3.
```

To fix this download correct version of the dependency from the [same site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libapt-pkg4.12).

And install that:

> sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb

Now you should be able to repeat the first command and install `apt`.

Note: The package versions may be different depending upon your version of Ubuntu. To locate the correct version use the menu in the header to select your ubuntu version:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to `su` to root in a tty environment (no gui) and then try `apt-get update` and/or `apt-get -f install`

Comment: How is this supposed to work? `apt` is not present on the system. You'll need to install the `deb` manually using `dpkg`.

Comment: apt-get is 99% of the time available on the core Debian system. but also its possible to download apt deb file and install manually via dpkg.

Comment: also, down vote is not ethical when it can be useful to others dude!

Comment: Its not a matter of ethics but of being relevant to the question. The question clearly states that `by mistake all the apt files are removed` which makes it fall under the other 1% on which `apt` isn't available. Modify your answer to take this under consideration and I'll remove my downvote. Nothing personal here.

Comment: according to logs, `apt` is available (otherwise the error would be `command not found`); just missing dependencies which either installing dependencies via `dpkg` or `apt-get -f install` will resolve the issue.

Comment: I think the log is pointing out the failure to install the apt `deb` file that user has manually downloaded. It does not indicate that apt is available as an installed package.

Answer (score 0):

Try with aptitude or download that particular package ( with dependencies if necessary ) and install it using dpkg -i  your-downloaded-packages*.deb

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner, it has helped me most of the time, when I get dependency issues.

Enter the following command `sudo dpkg install -f`. I hope this helps.